# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint in Sql Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a database with columns as first name lastname ,Id , date if arrival and  todays date. and all are data type of nchar(); I have ID as a primary key now in the web page i have entered vales and clicked on submit but is getting a error as

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint : Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Accomdation'.
The statement has been terminated.

Code is given as

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Accomdation;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    string f = TextBox1.Text;
    string g = TextBox5.Text;
    string d = DropDownList1.Text;
    string s = TextBox1.Text;
    string a = TextBox2.Text;
    string h = TextBox7.Text;
    string k = TextBox6.Text;
    string u = TextBox8.Text;
    string sql=("INSERT INTO Accomdation ([First Name], [LAst Name], Gender, [UHCL ID], [Date OF arrival], [FLight No], Email)VALUES        ('tya', 'tya', 'tya', 'tya', 'tya', 'tya', 'tya')");

    SqlCommand sw = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
```

Comment: Please look at your insert statement.

Comment: First, if your insert consists of the values `tya` repeatedly, you should be able to see the problem. Second, you need to learn to actually **read the words** of the error message, and you can see *exactly* what the problem is here.

Comment: @KenWhite You really want him to spend his brain instead of bothering other people? Come on - as long as many programmers are his level I can call in hugh daily rates.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not insert value for ID, you should make that ID as auto increment and not null.

something like below.

```
create table Accomdation(
   AccID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,

   define other columns 

 )
```

And use Parameterized queries with SqlCommand, here is sample code

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO Accomdation ([First Name], [LAst Name]) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is ID (primary key) an identity?  It needs to be.  Is the primary key a composite clustered index/how?
The error means that you are trying to insert something into the PK that already exists.

Select from the table and see what exists.  Try running just the insert statement in management studio, with different values.